# SwiftUI's new animation method only works combined with onTapGesture

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios15

I am trying to animate an arrow to make it flip 180 degrees when a button is tapped. But it only works when I use the onTapGesture method with nothing else inside. It also does not work if I change the rotation angle value somewhere else in the code. For instance:

This piece of code is properly animated

```
Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)

                                .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(self.rotationAngle))
                                .animation(.easeIn, value: self.rotationAngle)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    self.rotationAngle += 180

                                }
```

This one is not

```
  Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)

                                .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(self.rotationAngle))
                                .animation(.easeIn, value: self.rotationAngle)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    self.currentArrow.toggle()
                                    self.rotationAngle += 180
                                }
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The `.animation(.easeIn, value: self.rotationAngle)` modifier explicitly tells the view to animate when `self.rotationAngle` changes.

However, there's no such instruction for the `currentArrow` property changes, so the view doesn't animate when it changes.

To fix it, you can do either of two things:

A. Add a similar modifier for the `currentArrow` property:

```swift
.animation(.easeIn, value: currentArrow)
```

B. Toggle the value within a `withAnimation` block:

```swift
withAnimation {
    self.currentArrow.toggle()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: As @vadim-belyaev mentioned, using `withAnimation` will fix the animation but it only works if nothing else is inside the block. This will happen similarly with `onTapGesture`
My solution is as follows:

```
Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle")
   .resizable()
   .foregroundColor(.white)
   .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
   .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(self.rotationAngle))
   .animation(.easeIn, value: self.rotationAngle)
   .onTapGesture {
      withAnimation {
        self.rotationAngle += 180
      }
   }
```